# How can I add an Array of products in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, vite

I've been trying for almost 24 hours to insert an array of products (i had a page in my project just to store the array, for other pages to use it, but now im trying to put it in a Database)  into Firebase Realtime Database, so far without success and it seems to be a silly thing and even so I can't find the solution, I think that I'm making mistakes in the logic of the function and the imports, here are the pictures:

[image: Products page:]

[image: FirebaseConfig page:]

[image: FirebaseConfig imports:]

[image: Browser console error:]

I've tried chat Gpt and Firebase Doc help but it doesn't helped too!
I've tried to use this logic:

```
`import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
  const db = getDatabase();
  set(ref(db, 'users/' + userId), {
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
}`
```

I have tried this myself, and asked chat gpt to use this logic too and nothing works.
But maybe, it could be working already and just that im missing something in the imports, so maybe you guys could help.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

firebaseConfig is your default export not a named export.

Try changing your import on line 1 of produtos.jsx from

`import {firebaseConfig} from '../services/FirebaseConfig'`

to

`import firebaseConfig from '../services/FirebaseConfig'`

You only need to use the brackets for named exports.

Comment: Already tried this and not works!

Comment: @Davi hmm, did you get a different error though

Comment: No, it kept giving me the same error message! But, i was not returning nothing in the function "return", because my intention is to use that page only as a reference to send that same array to the Database! But i've changend plans recently, because this was preventing me of keep the prodution, so i decided to let it be just inside of my code for the moment, and ill try to implement the other funcionalities, and after i'll comeback to this and will let you know! Thanks!